# Renaming ASP.NET SQL tables

Tags: sql, asp.net

Im working with an ASP.NET boilerplate and would like to rename the sql tables it uses

I believe the relevant code is

```
public AlbumViewerContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {         
    }

    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set;  }
```

It also includes models for Albums, Artists, Tracks and Users

How would i go about changing the SQL table names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Table attribute on your Model. like as

```
[Table("Album")]
public class Album
{
 public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Id like the Album table renamed Report so how does that affect the code?

Comment: If you change your model name then you have to change the code as well. otherwise, there will be no issue.

Comment: So all i have to do is add your code and change table name?

Answer (score 0):

.Net Core solution:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "OldTableName", schema: "dbo", newName: "NewTableName", newSchema: "dbo");
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "NewTableName", schema: "dbo", newName: "OldTableName", newSchema: "dbo");
}
```